# Github actions ci cd failed

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-runners

hello i'm having some errors on github actions, following is my testing.yml file

```
name: Test

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
#on:
#push:
#branches: [ master ]
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Test
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: server_ip
          username: ubuntu,
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          script: |
            cd ~/test-cicd/ && touch help
        if: always()
```

the test fails and tells me the following error

```
2021/09/19 08:52:45 ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem, the problem was i put a comma on my username. It should be like this **`username: ubuntu`** not **`username: ubuntu,`**